# Posting to wordpress from a custom form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'll like to post a page from a custom PHP form. This custom form is outside the main wordpress folder. 
Here's my code :

```
<?php
require_once('../wp-config.php'); 

PostCreator('My Lorem Ipsum', 'page', 'With a sizable serving of Dolor. This was created using Harri Bell-Thomas\'s PostCreator function.');

if(!function_exists('PostCreator')) {

    function PostCreator(

        $name = 'AUTO POST',

        $type = 'post',

        $content = 'DUMMY CONTENT',

        $category = array(1,2),

        $template = NULL,

        $author_id = '1',

        $status = 'publish') {

        define('POST_NAME', $name);

        define('POST_TYPE', $type);

        define('POST_CONTENT', $content);

        define('POST_CATEGORY', $category);

        define('POST_TEMPLATE', '');

        define('POST_AUTH_ID', $author_id);

        define('POST_STATUS', $status);

        if ($type == 'page') {

            $post = get_page_by_title( 'POST_NAME', 'OBJECT', $type  );

            $post_id = $post->ID;

            $post_data = get_page($post_id);

            define('POST_TEMPLATE', $template);

        }

        else {

            $post = get_page_by_title( 'POST_NAME', 'OBJECT', $type  );

            $post_id = $post->ID;

            $post_data = get_post($post_id);

        }

        function hbt_create_post() {
            echo "HBT"."\n";

            $post_data = array(

                'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags('POST_NAME'),

                'post_content'  => 'POST_CONTENT',

                'post_status'   => 'POST_STATUS',

                'post_type'     => 'POST_TYPE',

                'post_author'   => 'POST_AUTH_ID',

                'post_category' => 'POST_CATEGORY',

                'page_template' => 'POST_TEMPLATE'

            );

            echo "POSTING...."."\n";
            wp_insert_post( $post_data, $error_obj );
            echo "POSTED"."\n";

        }

        if(!isset($post))
echo "WWWW";
            add_action('admin_init', 'hbt_create_post', 10 );
echo "SSS";
        return $error_obj;

    }

}

/* All available options for PostCreator()

PostCreator( 'TITLE' , 'POST TYPE' , 'POST CONTENT' , 'POST CATEGORY' , 'TEMPLATE FILE NAME' , 'AUTHOR ID NUMBER' , 'POST STATUS');

TITLE - HTML Stripped Out. Simple String.

POST TYPE - Post type slug. Eg 'post' or 'page'. Custom Post Types are supported.

POST CONTENT - Content of the Post/Page. HTML allowed.

POST CATEGORY - An array of the integer ID's  of the category/categories you want to link to your post

TEMPLATE FILE NAME - File name of the template. Only for Pages. In the format 'file_name.php'.

AUTHOR ID NUMBER - Integer value. Default is 1.

POST STATUS - Available options; [ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ]
If successful, PostCreator() returns nothing.

If there is an error PostCreator() returns a WP_error object.

*/

?>
```

The page is not inserted and I get that result :

```
Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values in /usr/local/www/nginx-dist/wordpress/autopost/PostCreator.php on line 28
WWWWSSS
```

so hbt_create_post is never called! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What's on line 28?

Comment: define('POST_CATEGORY', $category);